# Overhear and Eavesdrop

Tags: meaning

I am unsure about the relationship between overhearing and eavesdropping. Am I right to think that overhearing is always unintentional, and eavesdropping is always intentional? Or is eavesdropping a special case of overhearing, i.e. overhearing can refer to both intentional and unintentional circumstances?

Comment: I would say that *eavesdropping* is always intentional, although it may have started as a result of accidentally overhearing something.  Conversely, *overhearing* is usually unintentional, but may lead on to intentionally *eavesdropping*.

Comment: What TrevorD said, plus sometimes you can't stop overhearing even if you want to, because the people are speaking loud enough so you can't tune them out.  When you want to stop overhearing and can't, it is not eavesdropping.

Comment: Of course, a person who eavesdropped on a conversation is going to say they overheard it when gossiping with a friend. Eavesdropping is what others are doing to you. Overhearing is what you do to others. Eavesdropping generally implies you have gone out of your way to listen in on a conversation - that you are where you are for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

*Eavesdropping* is a kind of **listening** (it is done secretly).

*Overhearing* is a kind of **hearing** (it is accidental, or heard over other noise, or heard though it was not supposed to be).

The essential difference is that between listening and hearing. Listening is necessarily intentional; hearing is not; etc.

Answer (score 2):

Overhearing has nothing to do with intention but only with whether you hear or not. On the other hand, eavesdropping has nothing to do with whether you hear or not but only with intention. So, based on that, here's my answer to your questions:

> Am I right to think that overhearing is always unintentional, and eavesdropping is always intentional?

You're right as to only the second part of your question. Overhearing can be intentional or unintentional. And eavesdropping is always intentional.

> Or is eavesdropping a special case of overhearing, i.e. overhearing can refer to both intentional and unintentional circumstances?

No, eavesdropping is not a special case of overhearing even though overhearing can be intentional and unintentional. For example, when you're trying to eavesdrop but fail to hear anything, you're eavesdropping but not overhearing.